# Вывести в wordpress изображения имея их id

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть идентификаторы изображений.

Как мне, используя возможности `php` и `wordpress` и имея эти идентификаторы, вывести изображения?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вы хотите вывести изображения то подойдёт:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image

Если вам нужна только ссылка, то:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( 192 ); ?>" alt="" />
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image_url

Answer (score 1):

Ну например так:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_url($id);
```